# Conteo y Suma en Python

Tags: python

Hola a todos soy nuevo por aquí, recientemente empece un curso de Python y me llamo la atención este fragmento de código:

```
[print('',x, end='\t') for x in "Hello World"]; print()

[print(ord(x), end='\t') for x in "Hello World"]; print()
```

Básicamente lo que hace es esto, escribir debajo de cada letra su representación en código ascii.

```
H    e    l    l    o        W    o    r    l    d

72  101  108  108  111  32   87  111  114  108  100
```

Ahora bien mi pregunta es: ¿como puedo sumar el valor de la primera letra al valor de la segunda y el resultado sumarlo al valor de la tercera letra y así sucesivamente? para que quede algo así

```
H    e    l    l    o         W    o    r    l    d

72  173  281  389  500  532  619  730  844  952  1052
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una recomendación importante en Python: la comprensión de listas se usa para generar listas, no para reemplazar un `for` en la ejecución de un comando.

La versión correcta con comprensión de listas es:

```
texto = "Hello World"
print(''.join([f"{letra:>4}" for letra in texto]))
valores = [ord(letra) for letra in texto]
print(''.join([f"{valor:4}" for valor in valores]))
print(' '.join([f"{sum(valores[0:i + 1])}" for i in range(len(valores))]))
```

#### Análisis

Esta comprensión de lista toma cada letra del texto y la edita con formato alineado a la derecha, ocupando cuatro posiciones:

```
[f"{letra:>4}" for letra in texto])
```

produce:

```
['   H', '   e', '   l', '   l', '   o', '    ', '   W', '   o', '   r', '   l', '   d']
```

y sólo queda hacer el `join` para producir llegar a:

```
   H   e   l   l   o       W   o   r   l   d
```

A continuación generamos una lista con los valores decimales de cada letra:

```
valores = [ord(letra) for letra in texto]
```

produce:

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

Ahora imprimimos la lista con formato de cuatro espacios por valor:

```
print(''.join([f"{valor:4}" for valor in valores]))
```

Para la suma acumulada usamos la función `sum(lista)` sobre un **rango** de la lista `valores`. Usamos el `for i` para ir seleccionado un rango creciente de valores:

```
print(' '.join([f"{sum(valores[0:i + 1])}" for i in range(len(valores))]))
```

produce:

```
72 173 281 389 500 532 619 730 844 952 1052
```

#### Demo

```
texto = "Hello World"
print(''.join([f"{letra:>4}" for letra in texto]))
valores = [ord(letra) for letra in texto]
print(''.join([f"{valor:4}" for valor in valores]))
print(' '.join([f"{sum(valores[0:i + 1])}" for i in range(len(valores))]))
```

produce:

```
   H   e   l   l   o       W   o   r   l   d
  72 101 108 108 111  32  87 111 114 108 100
72 173 281 389 500 532 619 730 844 952 1052

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: En el join no es necesario usar [] como haces en esta linea: `''.join([f"{valor:4}" for valor in valores])`. Podrías quitarle los corchetes para que cree un objeto generador. Entonces la lista será recorrida una sola vez.

Comment: @DanteS. Pensé en esa posibilidad, pero tendría que entrar a explicar que es un generador a alguien que aún no se maneja con comprensión de listas. Encontré más apropiado mostrar una comprensión de listas bien ejecutada, algo que él pueda contrastar con algo conocido.

Comment: Ya veo. Es una buena idea!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, para ser sincero la pregunta planteada me llamo mucho la atención porque soy fan de criptografía, las claves secretas y los enigmas, y mi interés en este fragmento de código es poder ocuparlo a nivel personal con algunas modificaciones que espero poder aportar cuando haya concluido mi curso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo realice asi:

```
[print('',x, end='\t') for x in "Hello World"]; print()

suma = 0
for x in 'Hello World':
    suma= suma + ord(x)
    print(suma, end='\t')
```

Lo hice mediante el for normal, y declare una variable llamada suma donde almacenare la suma acumulada.

```
H   e   l    l   o       W  o   r   l    d

72 173 281 389 500 532 619 730 844 952 1052
```

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, creo que es una respuesta elegante y sencilla, como la ecuación de Euler.